# Can I run a liquibase command line to see what changeset will get applied

Tags: jenkins, liquibase

I'm running liquibase updates via Jenkins.  I'd like to see a listing of changesets that are applied in the console output. We are running an update, but it does not provided this information.  I see where the MAVEN plugin has **status** that would be nice to use, but I dod not see the same available in the command line.  Can somebody help point me to a command or command line option that will help provided such information so I can display in the Jenkins output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The status command is available in the command line a well. You can also run updateSQL which will list the actual SQL that will execute.

Comment: There is a status command & I use the --verbose option to be able to see the changeset that will be applied. here is an example of how i run it using parameters values: `echo "Running liquibase status command to generate the list of changesets that will be applied ..."
liquibase --driver=${liquibase.required.driver} --classpath=${liquibase.required.classpath} --url=${liquibase.required.url} --username=${liquibase.required.username} --password=${liquibase.required.password} --contexts=${liquibase.contexts} --logLevel=${liquibase.optional.logLevel} --changeLogFile=update.xml  status --verbose`